# Closing over a hash-map of functions in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a set of functions that all have the same first parameter.

```
(defn get-file [dir filename] ...)
(defn write-file [dir filename] ...)
```

I'd like to partially apply all of them at once, basically. Seems like I could wrap them all in a function like this:

```
(defn get-fns [dir]
  {:get-file (fn [filename] ...)
   :write-file (fn [filename] ...)})
```

But that seems like accessing the functions would be kind of annoying.

```
(let [fns (get-fns dir-name)]
  ((fns :get-file) filename)))
```

I suppose I could use a mutable `var` as well, but that doesn't seem very, well, functional. Is there a canonical/idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: Could you please provide example how you plan to use these functions (without closure on `dir` arg)?

Comment: What does *" partially apply all of them at once"* mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's think it through: you've got a list of things, and you want to apply something to each of them, so `map`.  What do you want to apply to them?  You want to partially apply the first argument, so `partial`.  Then you want to have a unique reference to each of those values, so use deconstruction on the list.

Adding all that up, assuming `dir`, `get-file`, and `write-file` are all defined, you'd do

```
(let [[get-file-here write-file-here] (map #(partial % dir) [get-file write-file])]
  ...)
```

Here's a full example

```
(let [[add-to-3 sub-from-3] (map #(partial % 3) [+ -])]
  (prn (add-to-3 2))                                    ; 5
  (prn (sub-from-3 5)))                                 ; -2
```

Answer (score 1):

So we want a series of partial applications that we can use in a local binding context.

```
(defn get-fns
  [dir]
  {:get-f (partial get-file dir)
   :write-f (partial write-file dir)})
```

Then, in a local binding, we can use them

```
(let [{:keys [get-f write-f]} (get-fns dir)]
   (get-f file-name))
```

(you are of course free to use your original keywords, by changing the keywords I make it unambiguous that `get-f` is coming from `get-fns` and is not the globally bound var).